# Extracting via HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack and trying to extract an image name from html.  Here's the html string I have:

```
sHtml = "<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>Here are some images.</br>1) < IMG style='MARGIN-BOTTOM: 20px; MARGIN-LEFT: 20px' align=right src='images/sample001.jpg'>2) < IMG style='MARGIN-BOTTOM: 25px; MARGIN-LEFT: 25px' align=right src='images/sample002.png'></br> And some docs as well.</br>1) href='javascript:parent.POPUP({url:'testDoc001.htm',type:'shared',width:600,height:645})'></br>2) href='javascript:parent.POPUP({url:'testDoc002.html',type:'shared',width:700,height:712})'></br></BODY></HTML>"
```

In WPF C# I pass this string into the following routine:

---

```
private static List<string> ExtractHtmlInfo(string sHtml)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(new StringReader(sHtml));
    HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentNode;

    List<string> anchorTags = new List<string>();

    //foreach (HtmlNode link in root.SelectNodes("//a"))
    foreach (HtmlNode link in root.SelectNodes("//img"))
        {
        string att = link.OuterHtml;
        anchorTags.Add(att);
    }

    return anchorTags;
}
```

---

When I step through the code I see that the line:

```
string att = link.OuterHtml;
```

provides the entire < img node ... which is more than I want.

I would like anchorTags to have just the folder and name of the file, as in:

```
[0] = images/sample001.jpg
[1] = images/sample002.png
```

So, I need something other than .OuterHtml but cannot find it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the values of the `src` attributes of the image elements:

```
foreach (HtmlNode img in root.SelectNodes("//img"))
{
    string att = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
    anchorTags.Add(att);
}
```

Comment: That's great Oded...just what I was looking for.  Another question, how would I extract the string 'testDoc001.htm' from this same example?  I tried to use root.SelectNode("//html=") but it does not like that.

Comment: @AnnSanderson - The `href` attributes of the `a` element would give the full contents of that. You could use `string.Split` to split those values further.

Comment: Hmmm...  I used ("//a") and then the href attribute and it gave me:  'javascript:parent.POPUP({url:' What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AnnSanderson - The problem is that the HTML is malformed. The `'` is used to delimit the `href` attribute but is being used within the `javascript` portion.

Comment: Is there anyway to get around this without changing the html so it is not malfunctioned?

Comment: @AnnSanderson - Malformed. It is not valid HTML. And no, there isn't. The "HTML" string is not valid HTML - it is broken and you can't expect HTML libraries to deal with it correctly.